# Python code runs without problems in Py2.7 but doesn't in 3.6.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, sublimetext3

I am trying to run the following code:

```
Headers=requests.get('https://coinmarketcap.com').headers
CookieDough=Headers['Set-Cookie']
Headers="""\"{
":authority":"coinmarketcap.com",
":method":"POST",
":path":"/login",
":scheme":"https",
"accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
"accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br",
"accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9",
"cache-control":"max-age=0",
"content-length":"743",
"content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
"cookie":\""""+CookieDough+"""\",
"origin":"https://coinmarketcap.com",
"referer":"https://coinmarketcap.com",
"upgrade-insecure-requests":"1",
"user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36"
}\""""

print(json.loads(Headers, strict=False))
```

On a past thread somebody has run this code on python 2.7 and it runs successfully, however when I run it on my end, python 3.6.4, it doesn't run. It gives me the following error:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 2 (char 4)
```

I am running Python 3.6.4 on the Sublime Text 3 Builder.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As posted your example is incomplete so it's hard to say for sure, but regardless of that are you sure that it works in Python 2.7, because it doesn't work for me in Python versions 2.7 or 3.6 without modifications.

Specifically, this is a problem:

```python
Headers="""\"{
}\""""
```

The first and last characters in the string are `\"`, which is a regular double quote character. That means that the value of `Headers` looks like this:

```json
"{
":authority":"coinmarketcap.com",
":method":"POST",
":path":"/login",
":scheme":"https",
"accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
"accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br",
"accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9",
"cache-control":"max-age=0",
"content-length":"743",
"content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
"cookie":"stuff",
"origin":"https://coinmarketcap.com",
"referer":"https://coinmarketcap.com",
"upgrade-insecure-requests":"1",
"user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36"
}"
```

This isn't valid JSON; it's a string with embedded newlines in it. Probably you want to remove the offending `\"` from the beginning and the end.

If the intention was to have it be a string that looks like it contains a dictionary, it's already that by definition and you don't need to use the `json` module to decode it as as string.

if the intention was to have it be a dictionary, removing those characters makes it valid again (assuming that whatever is in `CookieDough` is a valid JSON string).

Answer (score 0):

Line ***Headers*** is the problem it should be 

 `"{
":authority":"coinmarketcap.com",
":method":"POST",
":path":"/login",
":scheme":"https",
"accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
"accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br",
"accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9",
"cache-control":"max-age=0",
"content-length":"743",
"content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
"cookie":"stuff",
"origin":"https://coinmarketcap.com",
"referer":"https://coinmarketcap.com",
"upgrade-insecure-requests":"1",
"user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36"
}"`